# How can I access the parent usercontrols elements from the child user control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

How can I access the parent usercontrol's elements from the child user control in wpf ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find Parent control's by `GetParent()` method. If you want to find parent control in Templates you can take help of [RelativeSource FindAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you need those elements to get their values, e.g. for binding, you can use this construction (here the background of the element will be using the values of its parent):

`Background="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}`

In the code, for every element extending `FrameworkElement` class, there is [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, just cast it to the correct type (I assume you know, what type it is) and you're done.